# laravel 4 artisan make command - error Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, mcrypt

I'm trying to glean a signal from the noise in debugging this.

When I run `./artisan make:middleware MyTools`, I get:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required
```

Solutions seem to revolve around setting a proper value in `/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini` and then doing a `php5enmod mcrypt` and Apache restart.  Sounds good, and a `phpinfo()` call shows it's there and that I'm running PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20.  All peachy.

However, I'm not running php 5 on the command line for `artisan`!  Typing `php -v` tells me I'm running php 7.0.14-2.

When I go to `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available`, indeed I do not see `mcrypt.ini` - my question is how to "get" a proper mycrypt.ini file in there, have Mcrypt running for the *COMMAND LINE*, **and** not have to change anything else - for example I want to leave the webserver as it is at 5.5.9.  How do I do this?

-- UPDATE --

See the discussion/comments below, I was able to get around this by DOWNGRADING my CLI to 5.5.9 vs. installing mcrypt into php7.  This is not likely the best solution and I welcome a better one.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to remove php 7 from the execute path and instead use the same PHP version apache is using.

Comment: that sounds promising.  I have no idea what that means or where that is found (the "execute path").  Can you give details?

Comment: If you type `which php` in your command line you'll see which one runs when you run any `php ..` command. You can delete that file, and do `ln -s /path/to/php5/bin/php /usr/bin` to link the PHP 5 executable in the executable path

Comment: This worked.  Interestingly, `/usr/bin/php` was already a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/php` - I don't know why.  I first did a `cd /usr/bin`, then  `mv php phpx` for backup, then did `ln -s php5 php`.   Running `php -v` now from CL shows same version as webserver.  Thank you.